# 'ExceptT ResourceT' vs 'ResourceT ExceptT'

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Real World Haskell states that ["Transformer stacking order is important"](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html). However, I can't seem to figure out if there's a difference between `ExceptT (ResourceT m) a` and `ResourceT (ExceptT m) a`. Will they interfere with each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, there is no real difference between both orders. The reason being: unlike many transformers including `ExceptT`, the resource transformer does *not* “inject” its own doings into the base monad you apply it to, but rather start off the entire action with passing in the release references.

If you write out the types (I'll refer to `MaybeT` instead of `ExceptT` for the sake of simplicity; they're obviously equivalent for the purpose of this question) then you have basically

```
type MaybeResourceT m a = MaybeT (IORef RelMap -> m a)
                        = IORef RelMap -> m (Maybe a)
type ResourceMaybeT m a = ResourceT (m (Maybe a))
                        = IORef RelMap -> m (Maybe a)
```

i.e. actually equivalent types. I suppose you could also show that for the operations.